# Sqlite Select Query with rawQuery at Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I know it is a basic question, but i can not find problem.
I try to get some columns with rawQuery.

```
    SQLiteDatabase db=database.getReadableDatabase();

    try 
    {
       String sql="SELECT * FROM CAR WHERE name = "; 
       Cursor crs = db.rawQuery(sql+"5P", null);
    }
```

I always get the same exception.

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: **unrecognized token**: "5P": , while compiling: SELECT * FROM CAR WHERE name = 5P
```

I have 5P at CAR table, i am sure because i used it other queries.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You either need to quote that value, or better yet, use positional parameters:

```
String[] args={"5P"};
Cursor crs=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM CAR WHERE name = ?", args);
```

The advantage of using positional parameters is that SQLite will handle quoting the string, escaping any embedded quotes, etc.