# Conflict with both CursorLoader and simple startManagingCursor

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursorloader

I read the data from db by CursorLoader, but the search method uses startmanaging cursor. The application has a mistake - 10-25 11:42:53.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1461): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Is there any way to use only CursorLoader for both reading database and search and how I can do it in my code? Thanks!

```
package com.example.citycode;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

  ListView lvData;
  DBHelper db;
  SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter;

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
      String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
      doMySearch(query);
    }

    // Открываем подключение к БД
    db = new DBHelper(this);
    db.open();

    // Формируем столбцы сопоставления
    String[] from = new String[] { DBHelper.COLUMN_r_name, DBHelper.COLUMN_region, DBHelper.COLUMN_code};
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.city_name, R.id.region_name, R.id.city_code };

    // Создаем адаптер и настраиваем список
    scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, null, from, to, 0);
    lvData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listdata);
    lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter);

    // Создаем лоадер для чтения данных
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);


  }

  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Закрываем подключение к БД при выходе
    db.close();
  }

  public void doMySearch(String query) {
        db = new DBHelper(this);
        db.open();
        //Ищем совпадения
        Cursor cursor1 = db.fetchRecordsByQuery(query);
        startManagingCursor(cursor1);
        String[] from = new String[] { DBHelper.COLUMN_r_name, DBHelper.COLUMN_region, DBHelper.COLUMN_code};
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.city_name, R.id.region_name, R.id.city_code };

        SimpleCursorAdapter records = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.item, cursor1, from, to);
        //Обновляем адаптер
        lvData.setAdapter(records);
      }

     @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_main, menu);

        // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).getActionView();
        // Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
        //searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            //onSearchRequested();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

  @Override
  public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bndl) {
    return new MyCursorLoader(this, db);
  }

  @Override
  public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    scAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
  }

  @Override
  public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
  }

  static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {

      DBHelper db;

    public MyCursorLoader(Context context, DBHelper db) {
      super(context);
      this.db = db;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {
      Cursor cursor = db.getAllData();
      try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return cursor;
    }

  }
}
```

Here is the log:

```
10-25 13:09:58.351: D/AndroidRuntime(4639): Shutting down VM
10-25 13:09:58.351: W/dalvikvm(4639): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416d7ba8)
10-25 13:09:58.351: E/AndroidRuntime(4639): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-25 13:09:58.351: E/AndroidRuntime(4639): Process: com.example.citycode, PID: 4639
10-25 13:09:58.351: E/AndroidRuntime(4639): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.citycode/com.example.citycode.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-25 13:09:58.351: E/AndroidRuntime(4639):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
10-25 13:09:58.351: E/AndroidRuntime(4639):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
10-25 13:09:58.351: E/AndroidRuntime(4639):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-25 13:09:58.351: E/AndroidRuntime(4639):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
10-25 13:09:58.351: E/AndroidRuntime(4639):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-25 13:09:58.351: E/AndroidRuntime(4639):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-25 13:09:58.351: E/AndroidRuntime(4639):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
10-25 13:09:58.351: E/AndroidRuntime(4639):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-25 13:09:58.351: E/AndroidRuntime(4639):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-25 13:09:58.351: E/AndroidRuntime(4639):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
10-25 13:09:58.351: E/AndroidRuntime(4639):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
10-25 13:09:58.351: E/AndroidRuntime(4639):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-25 13:09:58.351: E/AndroidRuntime(4639): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-25 13:09:58.351: E/AndroidRuntime(4639):     at com.example.citycode.MainActivity.doMySearch(MainActivity.java:75)
10-25 13:09:58.351: E/AndroidRuntime(4639):     at com.example.citycode.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
10-25 13:09:58.351: E/AndroidRuntime(4639):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
10-25 13:09:58.351: E/AndroidRuntime(4639):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-25 13:09:58.351: E/AndroidRuntime(4639):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
10-25 13:09:58.351: E/AndroidRuntime(4639):     ... 11 more
10-25 13:09:59.881: I/Process(4639): Sending signal. PID: 4639 SIG: 9
```

I use two queries from db class to get the data:

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM city AS t1, region AS t2 WHERE t1.region_number = t2._id;";

// Получить все данные из БД
public Cursor getAllData() {
  return  myDataBase.rawQuery(sqlQuery, new String[] {});
}

  String sqlQuery1 = "SELECT * FROM city AS t1, region AS t2 ON t1.region_number = t2._id WHERE t1.name LIKE '%' || ? || '%';";

     //Поиск запросом LIKE
  public Cursor fetchRecordsByQuery(String query) {
      return  myDataBase.rawQuery(sqlQuery1, new String[] {query});
  }
```

Comment: pls attach the exception log.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to filter the ListView you would normally make the search method call restartloader with a Arguments Bundle containing a Selection.

more or less pseudo code, as i did not tested it:

So unfiltered in onCreate you call : getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

in search() you would do something like this:

```
public void search(String searchName){
  Bundle args = new Bundle();
  args.put(KEY_SELECTION, searchName);
  getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, args, this);
}
```

in your onCreateLoader Callback read the searchName from the args and give it to your CursorLoader implementation. There you have to provide a query possibility which accepts a String and filters the Cursor by this String. if you use a contentProvider it is a bit easier as you just have to provide the Selection and URI and are ready to go.

a good overview is provided here: [Loaders](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/using-loaders-in-android/)

**EDIT:**
no you do not need two loaders at the same time, assuming you will only show one List with either unfiltered data (all rows) OR filtered data (rows mathing your request query string.
You would use one Loader with either a "WHERE yourcolumn LIKE 'querystring'" or without a WHERE-clause.

One simple example which you can easily adopt to your approach using the database without a contentprovide directly would be:

```
public boolean onQueryTextChanged(String newText) {
// Called when the action bar search text has changed.  Update
// the search filter, and restart the loader to do a new query
// with this filter.
mCurFilter = !TextUtils.isEmpty(newText) ? newText : null;
getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
return true;
}

public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
// NOTE: The Loader is instantiated with the user's query  

// Now create and return a CursorLoader that will take care of
// creating a Cursor for the data being displayed.
return new MyCursorLoader(getActivity(), dbHelper, mCurFilter);
}



static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {

  DBHelper db;
String mCurFilter;

public MyCursorLoader(Context context, DBHelper db, String filter) {
  super(context);
  this.db = db;
this.mCurFilter = filter;
}

@Override
public Cursor loadInBackground() {
  Cursor cursor = null;
 if (mCurFilter != null) {
   cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE name = ? , new String[]{mCurFiler});
} else {
     cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM example_table);
}
  return cursor;
}

}
```

Comment: How can I filter the Cursor by string. I supposed I need 2 Cursors from two queries - the first selects all data from db, the second selects data using LIKE "query".

Comment: you dont need two cursor at a time. You need two cursor one after another. you populate lvData with scAdapter. onLoadFinished gets called after initLoader and restartLoader, and you there just call swapCursor on the scAdapter to switch the contents of the listView. I understood that you dont show both results at the same time. querying by string works as described here with a rawQuery, but there ar numerous other possibilities: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136688/sqlite-select-query-with-rawquery-at-android[/link]

Comment: Still don't understand how it can work :( May be I need two loaders for each data? How to implement it in my code? Could you please show? I added logs and the description of DB queries.